# Why only the values of the left column are okay?

Tags: c

I have been trying to go through the code but I can't manage to find the error. I am trying to store the values in a struct in pairs of two. The problem is that I only manage to get the first element of each struct correct.

```
int main()
{

    struct Data
    {
        int col; // Der
        int row; // Izq
    };
    struct Data csv[10];

    int arrIn[4][2];
    int row0  = 0;
    int i; // Variable i
    // const char var[2] = ",";
    // char *token;
    const str[60];
    // token = strtok(str, var);
    int change;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("in.csv", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        fgets(str, 60, fp);  
        puts(str);// Values appear as (a,b)
        change = atoi(str);
        csv[i].col, csv[i].row = change;
    }    

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d      %d", csv[i].row, csv[i].col);
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `csv[i].col, csv[i].row = change;` does not do what you think. Try `csv[i].col = csv[i].row = change;`. Although we don't know if there is another value in the input string, which considering the "csv" clues, there probably is.

Comment: If the input is actually `(a, b)` with the parentheses and the comma, then `atoi(str)` will fail (silently) and return `0`. You have no attempt at parsing the input string.

Comment: `atoi(str)` only converts the initial int in the string.  If you want the second number, you might be better off using `sscanf`

Answer (score 1):

When you have a text string in the form

```
 number1,number2
```

you can't split it simply by doing

```
    change = atoi(str);
    csv[i].col, csv[i].row = change;
```

Instead you can use `sscanf` like

```
if (sscanf(str, "%d,%d", &csv[i].col, &csv[i].row) != 2) exit(1);
```

If the form is

```
 (number1,number2)
```

simply do

```
if (sscanf(str, "(%d,%d", &csv[i].col, &csv[i].row) != 2) exit(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for! Take care!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @4386247 said you also forgot to declare the type for the array str. I would post this as a comment but I don't have enough rep.